# How to handle DiscordHTTPError: 401 Unauthorized on GET /api/v7/users/@me

Tags: node.js, express, discord.js

I want to redirect users to login page if the access_token is invalid

I'm using [discord-oauth2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-oauth2).

```
  if (key != '0' && key != null && key != undefined) {
oauthclient.getUser(key).then((data)=>{
  console.log(data)
});}
```

but if the token is invalid, like `abcdefg` the I get 401 error

`(node:12732) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordHTTPError: 401 Unauthorized on GET /api/v7/users/@me`

how I can redirect to `/login` if I get 401 error